# 塗りつぶしがされている文字の検索方法について

Tags: vba, ms-word

WordのVBAの塗りつぶしプロパティについて質問です。

＜やりたいこと＞
番号リストVBAで、灰色で塗りつぶしがされている部分を検索・Selectionを取得する）
塗りつぶしがされている部分について塗りつぶしを解除してその部分の前後に、"<" ">"を入れたい

＜作ってみたけど上手く動かなかったコード＞
検索オプションとしてShading.BackgroundPatternColorIndexを選択してみたのですが、それを設定すると条件に引っかからなくなりました。

どなたか方法をご存知の方、ご教授していただくと本当に助かります。
宜しくお願いします。

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range
    With Selection.Find
    .Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = 16
    Do While .Execute
      Selection.Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = 0
      Selection.Range.InsertAfter Text:=">**"
    　Selection.Range.InsertBefore Text:="**<"
    Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: あわせて読みたい https://teratail.com/questions/247136

Answer (score 0):

通常のRangeについて蛍光ペンの色を取得/設定する時は[Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.shading.backgroundpatterncolorindex?view=word-pia)ではなく[HighlightColorIndex](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/word.range.highlightcolorindex)を使うようです。

[【コード】特定の色の蛍光ペンを消すWordマクロ](https://www.wordvbalab.com/code/5082/)の記事を参考に書き換えると良いでしょう。
下記はサンプルコードです。
サンプルコードでは行全体がハイライトされているとInsertAfterが次の項目の行頭に挿入されますのでご承知おきください。

```
Sub ModifyHighlights()
    ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
    With Selection.Find
        .Highlight = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        Do While .Execute
            If Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = 16 Then
                Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
                Selection.Range.InsertAfter Text:=">**" 
                Selection.Range.InsertBefore Text:="**<" 
            End If
            Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```